# Transloco configuration missingHandler.logMissingKey

Tags: transloco

I have an Angular component that gets a TranslocoService injected into the constructor.  The point of this component is to use the key provided as the output of the transform method in the event the key isn't found. This is done to make migrating existing components easier so I don't have to do them all at once.

The problem I'm having is that if I do this in the constructor in my component the config setting doesn't seem to have any affect.
`this.translocoService.config.missingHandler.logMissingKey = false;`

What am I missing here?

The translate function is as follows:

```
transform(contentKey: string, l10nBasePath: string): string {
    const translatedText: string = this.translocoService.translate(l10nBasePath + '.' + contentKey);

    if (translatedText !== null) {
      return translatedText;
    }

    return contentKey;
  }
```

Comment: did you solve it ?

Comment: @serrulien - No, I haven't.